# Building vuejs application doesn't build relative file references correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When running : `npm run build` it generates a html file containing references to the generated scripts. However, the link looks like this :

```
/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js
```

There is no period at the beginning so I get errors in the console saying the files can't be found. When I manually add the period, it works fine. Where does this get generated from ?

Comment: Try to set the `publicPath` in the `output` object and set it to `/`.

Comment: @Thoomas that worked. In the index.js file under the config directory, I had to change the build.assetsPublicPath from '/' to './'. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Thoomas in the comments I figured out how to solve this issue.

In the index.js file under the config directory, I had to change the build.assetsPublicPath from '/' to './'.

This now builds with the correct relative paths.